# How to generate master keys for new apps

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

When migrating an existing app to to my own Parse server, I can re-use the client/JS/etc. keys from the Parse.com dashboard. But how can I generate these keys when starting a fresh app on my server, and are there instructions on how to generate 'good' app IDs and master keys? As long as Parse.com is still up and running, I can use the dashboard for that; but in the long run this doesn't feel right.

Comment: I think it can be any string that has the same length as the keys you see in dashboard

Comment: Hmm,  but i want a specific button on dashboard to generate it.  So?

Comment: it s open source, feel free to create it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a masterkey by generating a random ID with an [online UUID generator](https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=uuid%20generator) or simply by closing your eyes and pressing random keys on the keyboard ;).

From the parse-server [README.md](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/0b88302beab5e8cc71baffcee8f6bcd056c80a11/README.md#basic-options):

> - `masterKey` (required) - The master key to use for overriding ACL security.  **You can use any arbitrary string.** Keep it secret! For
>     migrated apps, this should match your hosted Parse app.